# Switch between OverlayItems which share same GeoPoint

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

Hi I've populate a MapView on Android with several OverlayItems using ItemizedOverlay. But it can be that two ore more items share the same GeoPoint, meaning they are drawed on top of another OverlayItem.

Is there a possibility to switch on tap of one between theese items? At the iPhone map this is the default behaviour.